# List elements replace with other elements in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this problem in prolog to solve , this are the goals

```
a) ?- replace_var_args(father(yannis,X), [anna], NewTerm). NewTerm =
father(yannis,anna),
b) ?- replace_var_args(f(a,X,g(b), Y,h(a,Z)), [b,c], NewTerm). NewTerm =
f(a,b,g(b),c,h(a,Z)),
c) ?- replace_var_args(f(a,X,f(b),Y,h(a,Z)), [b,c,d], NewTerm). NewTerm =
f(a,b,g(b),c,h(a,d)).
d) ?- replace_var_args(t(X, Y, Z,a,f(Z,b)), [1,2,3], NewTerm). NewTerm =
t(1,2,3,a,f(Z,b)).
I have created this 
replace_var_args1(Old,Term,New):-atomic(Term),Term=Old.
replace_var_args1(Old,Term,Term):-var(Term).
replace_var_args1(Old,Term,Term):-nonvar(Term),atomic(Term),Term\==Old.

replace_var_args1(Old,Term,Term1):- \+ atomic(Term),functor(Term,F,N),functor(Term1,F,N),replace_var_args2(N,Old,Term,Term1).

replace_var_args(Old,Term,New):- replace_var_args1(Old,Term,New).
```

but its not working....

Comment: Are you allowed to use copy_term and term_variables? Cause then I think it's just a question taking the variables from 'Old' and unifying them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to use term_variables and don't mind the lack of elegance:

```
replace_var_args(Old,LARGS,New):-
    term_variables(Old,LIST),
    unify_var(LIST,LARGS),
    New = Old.

unify_var([],_):-!.
unify_var(_,[]):-!.
unify_var([A|T],[A|Z]):- unify_var(T,Z).
```

A lot more explicit than needed (i.e. 'New = Old' instead of using the same variable through and through) and with cuts, but it works for all of your examples.

Comment: i put in sicstus the library that contains this predicate but it doesnt recognise it :( why i put this in the pl file   use_module(library(terms)). @vmg

Comment: Did you insert a directive like so `:- use_module(library(terms)).`? Mind the `:-`. Put that line at the top of file you're consulting.

Comment: it worked it was sicstus bug i restarted it , consulted the file and it worked! You saved me ,thanks a lot from my heart!!i had to use functor,var and nonvar predicates but as long as i have found a solution !!